# TFS query Column option not showing all the columns

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2010, tfs-query

I have a column in WIT (work item template) named " Planned end date" and Reference as "SV.Deadline" . But when i create a query, and want to add this column to appear in query through "Column Options" , i do not find this column in the list.

Can anybody help ?

Also how can i delete a work item from TFS in VS2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you choose the correct work item type in the column dialog? Did you [refresh your cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716728.aspx)?

To delete a work item type use [witadmin destroywitd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd312129.aspx)

To delete a work item use [witadmin destroywi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236908.aspx)